# Python Pandas - Date comparison works one statement at a time, but not together when using the &

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and I am trying to pull the rows that are greater than a date and less than another date. If I run the greater and less than dates separately, it works. If I use the & and try to do both at the same time, I get an error. Any ideas?

Error I am getting is:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'int'

This Works:

```
df_subset = (df.loc[(df['dump_date'].dt.date >= start)])
```

This Does Not Work

```
df_subset = (df.loc[(df['dump_date'].dt.date >= start)]) & (df.loc[(df['dump_date'].dt.date <= end)])
```

Comment: Use a **single** `loc`: `df_subset = df.loc[(df['dump_date'].dt.date >= start) & (df['dump_date'].dt.date <= end)]`, or maybe better: `df_subset = df.loc[df['dump_date'].dt.date.between(start, end, inclusive='both')]`

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I took out the df.loc from each statement and it pulled in correctly. Thank you.